# Angularjs dropdown grouping

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do i group dropdown values in Angularjs?

HTML:

```
<div ng-model="tsInput" id="tsInput"
    name="tsInput" multi-select input-model="atsInDB"
    output-model="atsOut" button-label="shortenedName"
    item-label="shortenedName" tick-property="ticked" max-height="500px"
    selection-mode="single" max-labels="0" orientation="vertical"
    default-label="{{'MUSELECTED'|translate}}" helper-elements="filter"
    on-item-click="updateProfileList()"
    on-enter="handleInput(labelFilter)"
    group-property="categoryName">
</div>
```

Js code

```
tsInput = 
SkillNotInProfile: true
categoryName: "Others"
categoryUUID: ""
description: "Test description"
name: "CSV"
shortenedName: "<span title="Comma-separated values (CSV)">Others : CSV</span>"
```

I expect the grouped dropdown values like https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup 
Please note that the above link is just output reference only.

Comment: It's not clear how your Js code relates to the html template, please make sure that your code block formatting looks correct in the preview pane before posting. I think there is enough information here to answer the question but the JS clock is confusing.